Why in my code I always get User 'bb0d9bead54859' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 20)
I just deployed an app on Heroku and I have errors with my code and my database. In the database panel in Heroku there are a lot of connections which are not closing. I'm using connections pools and connection release. I'm using node.js and MySQL.
This is the error what i get: code:
'ER_USER_LIMIT_REACHED',
  errno: 1226,
  sql: 'SELECT users.id, users.name, users.email, users.goals, users.assists, users.team_name, users.profilePic, users.matches_played, users.cleansheets, users.season_name, teams.logo AS team_logo, country.flag_name, country.country_name \n' +
    '        FROM users\n' +
    '        LEFT JOIN teams ON users.team_name = teams.team_name\n' +
    '        LEFT JOIN country ON users.country_id = country.id\n' +
    "        WHERE users.id = '1'",
  sqlState: '42000',
  sqlMessage: "User 'bb0d9bead54859' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 20)"

This is part of my code.
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
const multer = require("multer");

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Configurare baza de date MySQL
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: "",
  user: "bb0d9bead54859",
  password: "",
  database: "",
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: 7,
  queueLimit: 0,
});

// Secretul pentru JWT
const jwtSecret =
  "uK9!xP2@vQ7#hD6$eB4%rT8&fL1*zM3^jW5(yN0)qE9*sR2@lF7#zH8&kJ1$uT4";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    cb(null, uniqueSuffix + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/; // Tipuri de fișiere acceptate
    const extname = filetypes.test(
      path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase()
    );
    const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

    if (mimetype && extname) {
      return cb(null, true);
    }
    cb(new Error("Tip de fișier invalid. Acceptăm doar imagini."));
  },
});

// Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
      scriptSrc: [
        "'self'",
        "https://esportshaxball-84079547de49.herokuapp.com",
      ], // Adaugă aici domeniul tău
      connectSrc: [
        "'self'",
        "https://esportshaxball-84079547de49.herokuapp.com",
      ], // Permite conexiuni la domeniul tău
    },
  })
);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname))); // Servește fișiere statice
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));

// Verificare conexiune la baza de date
async function checkDatabaseConnection() {
  try {
    const connection = await pool.getConnection();
    console.log("Conexiune la baza de date realizată cu succes!");
    connection.release(); // Eliberează conexiunea
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Eroare la conectarea la baza de date:", err.message);
  }
}

checkDatabaseConnection();

// Middleware pentru verificarea token-ului
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];

  if (!token) {
    console.log("Token is missing."); // Log pentru debugging
    return res.status(403).json({ message: "Token-ul este necesar." });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Invalid token:", err); // Log pentru debugging
      return res.status(403).json({ message: "Token invalid." });
    }
    req.user = decoded;
    console.log("Token valid:", req.user); // Log pentru debugging
    next();
  });
}

// Endpoint pentru înregistrare
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  let connection;
  try {
    connection = await pool.getConnection(); // Obține conexiunea din pool
    const [existingUser] = await connection.query(
      "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?",
      [email]
    );

    if (existingUser.length > 0) {
      return res.status(400).send("Email-ul este deja utilizat.");
    }

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    const user = { name, email, password: hashedPassword };

    await connection.query("INSERT INTO users SET ?", user);

    res.send(`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="ro">
      <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>Înscriere reușită</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <h1>Înregistrare reușită!</h1>
          <p>Contul tău a fost creat cu succes.</p>
          <a href="/login.html">Înapoi la pagina de logare</a>
      </body>
      </html>
    `);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Eroare la înregistrarea userului:", err);
    res.status(500).send(`Eroare la înregistrarea userului: ${err.message}`);
  } finally {
    if (connection) connection.release(); // Asigură-te că eliberezi conexiunea
  }
});

// Endpoint pentru obținerea numărului total de utilizatori
app.get("/totalUsers", async (req, res) => {
  let connection;
  try {
    connection = await pool.getConnection(); // Obține conexiunea din pool
    const [rows] = await connection.query(
      "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM users"
    );

    res.json({ total: rows[0].total });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Eroare la obținerea numărului total de utilizatori:", err);
    res.status(500).send("Eroare la obținerea numărului total de utilizatori.");
  } finally {
    if (connection) connection.release(); // Asigură-te că eliberezi conexiunea
  }
});

// Endpoint pentru autentificare
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, password } = req.body;

  // Verifică dacă utilizatorul este deja conectat
  const token = req.headers["authorization"];
  if (token) {
    return res.status(403).send("Utilizatorul este deja conectat.");
  }

  let connection;
  try {
    connection = await pool.getConnection(); // Obține conexiunea din pool
    const [rows] = await connection.query(
      "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?",
      [name]
    );

    if (rows.length === 0) {
      return res.status(401).send("Username or password wrong!");
    }

    const user = rows[0];
    const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!match) {
      return res.status(401).send("Username or password wrong!");
    }

    // Logare reușită
    const newToken = jwt.sign(
      { id: user.id, name: user.name, email: user.email },
      jwtSecret,
      { expiresIn: "1h" }
    );

    // Afișează mesajul de logare reușită
    res.json({ token: newToken, name: user.name, userId: user.id });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Eroare la autentificare:", err);
    res.status(500).send("Eroare la procesarea autentificării.");
  } finally {
    if (connection) connection.release(); // Asigură-te că eliberezi conexiunea
  }
});

// Endpoint pentru deconectare
app.post("/logout", (req, res) => {
  // Deconectarea este gestionată pe client prin ștergerea token-ului
  res.send("Utilizatorul a fost deconectat.");
});

// Endpoint pentru obținerea listei de utilizatori cu logo-ul echipei
app.get("/users", async (req, res) => {
  const connection = await pool.getConnection();
  try {
    const query = `
      SELECT 
        users.id, 
        users.name, 
        users.profilePic, 
        teams.logo 
      FROM users 
      LEFT JOIN teams ON users.team_name = teams.team_name
    `;
    const [rows] = await connection.query(query);
    res.json(rows);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Eroare la obținerea utilizatorilor:", err);
    res.status(500).send("Eroare la obținerea utilizatorilor.");
  } finally {
    connection.release(); // Eliberarea conexiunii
  }
});


I want the connections to close so my database can work properly and without errors.

This question is similar to: has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
